# Hiding Elements in C# UWP Webview without the user seeing it "disappear"

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

Curious one; I'm working on a webview as a part of a C# UWP project. The webpage is remote and not hosted by me and I use the `webView.InvokeScriptAsync` to inject my own JS code that hides the navigation menu of the website in question.

It works fine; but the user can "see" it is getting hidden. The page loads, user can briefly see the navigation menu just before it gets hidden by the injected JS code.

I have put the `InvokeScriptAsync` in the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Anyone have any tips here? Is there a way this can be hidden with the user being none the wiser? It looks pretty unprofessional when you can see the "hiding process" is taking place.

Comment: Can you inject some CSS to hide the element instead?

Comment: Well that's what I'm doing. as far as im aware you can only inject JS so im injecting JS that alters the CSS of the necessary elements...i could be wrong though?

Comment: @KamranRastegar Yeah. You're on the right way.

Answer (score 0):

webView_DOMContentLoaded worked for me.